how to count the depth of childrens of an array - Vue.js
I would like the calculate depth method to calculate the depth correctly and instead it is calculating in reverse assigning the first element with depth 2, the second with depth 1 and the third with depth 0, perhaps I need to create a new method where it receives the revisionData and then see item by item. And does not calculate for any reason a depth greater than 2.
<template>
      <acc-data-table-v2
            :data="revisionData"
            :columns="columns"
            primaryColumn="id"
            treeRowKey="id"
            row-key="id"
            :treeProps="{children: 'children'}"
            :row-class-name="tableRowClassName"
            >

            <template v-slot:subflowsRevisionsDescriptionTemplate="slotProps">
                <div>
                        <div :style="{ marginLeft: calculateMarginLeft(calculateDepth(slotProps.scope.row)) }">
                            <div v-if="slotProps.scope.row.step_id">
                                {{ slotProps.scope.row.step.description }} 
                            </div>
                            <div v-if="!slotProps.scope.row.step_id">
                                {{ slotProps.scope.row.description }} 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </template>
      </acc-data-table-v2>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      revisionData: [
        {
          id: 1, //depth: 0
          name: 'Parent 1',
          children: [
            {
              id: 11, //depth: 1
              name: 'Child 1.1',
              children: [
                {
                  id: 111, //depth: 2
                  name: 'Grandchild 1.1.1'
                },
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 12, //depth: 1
              name: 'Child 1.2'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2, //depth:0
          name: 'Parent 2',
          children: [
            {
              id: 21, //depth: 1
              name: 'Child 2.1'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
        calculateMarginLeft(depth) {
            const marginLeft = depth * 12 + 'px';
            return marginLeft;
        },
        calculateDepth(item) {
            let depth = 0;
            let parent = item;
            while (parent.children && parent.children.length > 0) {
                depth++;
                parent = parent.children[0];
            }
            return depth;
        },
  }
};
</script>


Isn't id: 111 supposed to be depth: 2?

@kissu yes and it is there

Sorry if I misunderstand but what is the issue here? Btw, this looks like something that you're trying to do: https://vuejs.org/examples/#tree

@kissu the issue here is that this is calculating the depth in the wrong way

Oh because this.calculateDepth(this.revisionData[0].children[0].children[0]) gives 0 while it is at depth 2? Makes sense because there is nothing there once you're at the bottom of the tree. You could always get the maximum of a given tree and then make maximum - currentDepthLevel so that way you could get 2 - 0 = 2 for your 111 value. Or you could do the opposite, and try to get the parent once deeply nested. That way, 1 will have 0 parents, while 111 will have 2 parents. Nvm it is not possible haha.

@kissu I don't want it to have a maximum, I want it to be recursive

Both are unrelated. Computing a maximum can be either iterative or recursive. Recursive functions are not that performant in JS but they are at least fitting in this case.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is a classic tree depth problem.
Update your code like the following:

create a computed value revisionDataWithDepth that is a copy of revisionData with an additional field depth
pass this revisionDataWithDepth to your :data
to get left margin call calculateMarginLeft(slotProps.scope.row.depth)

<template>
      <acc-data-table-v2
            :data="revisionDataWithDepth"
            :columns="columns"
            primaryColumn="id"
            treeRowKey="id"
            row-key="id"
            :treeProps="{children: 'children'}"
            :row-class-name="tableRowClassName"
            >

            <template v-slot:subflowsRevisionsDescriptionTemplate="slotProps">
                <div>
                        <div :style="{ marginLeft: calculateMarginLeft(slotProps.scope.row.depth) }">
                            <div v-if="slotProps.scope.row.step_id">
                                {{ slotProps.scope.row.step.description }} 
                            </div>
                            <div v-if="!slotProps.scope.row.step_id">
                                {{ slotProps.scope.row.description }} 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </template>
      </acc-data-table-v2>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      revisionData: [
        {
          id: 1, //depth: 0
          name: 'Parent 1',
          children: [
            {
              id: 11, //depth: 1
              name: 'Child 1.1',
              children: [
                {
                  id: 111, //depth: 2
                  name: 'Grandchild 1.1.1'
                },
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 12, //depth: 1
              name: 'Child 1.2'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2, //depth:0
          name: 'Parent 2',
          children: [
            {
              id: 21, //depth: 1
              name: 'Child 2.1'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    revisionDataWithDepth: function() {
      // create local function that creates a copy of revisionData with depth included
      function withDepth(revisions, currentDepth) {
        if (!revisions || !revisions.length) {
          return [] // or return undefined
        }
    
        const revisionsWithDepth = [];
        for (const revision of revisions) {
          const revWithDepth = { ...revision };
          revWithDepth.depth = currentDepth;
          revWithDepth.children = withDepth(revision.children, currentDepth + 1);
          revisionsWithDepth.push(revWithDepth);
        }
        return revisionsWithDepth;
      }
      return withDepth(this.revisionData, 0);
    }
  }
  methods: {
        calculateMarginLeft(depth) {
            const marginLeft = depth * 12 + 'px';
            return marginLeft;
        },
  }
};
</script>

Tip: you can even use a one-liner for withDepth:
function withDepth(revisions, depth) {
  return (revisions ?? []).map(revision => ({ ...revision, depth, children: withDepth(revision.children, depth + 1) }))
}


It's quite a simple recursive function:
Iterate over the array and assign each element the current depth. If an element has children call the function recusively with the incremented depth. The maximum depth is the maximum depth of any of the children.


function calcDepth(array, d) {
  let maxDepth = d;
  for (let elem of array) {
    elem.depth = d;
    if (elem.children?.length)
      maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, calcDepth(elem.children, d + 1));
  }
  return maxDepth;
}

let test = [ 
  { 
    id: "1", 
    children: [
      { 
        id: "1.1", 
        children: []
       }
    ]
  },
{ 
    id: "2", 
    children: [
      { 
        id: "2.1", 
        children: [
          {
            id: "2.1.1",
            children: [
              {
                id: "2.1.1.1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
       }
    ]
  }  
];

let max = calcDepth(test,0);
console.log(test);
console.log("MaxDepth: ", max);




Ok so you can try in modifying the code a bit ig
calculateDepth(item) {
  let depth = 0;
  let parent = item;
  // if there is no parent or any parent doesnt have child elemen`
  while (parent && parent.children && parent.children.length > 0) {
    depth++;
    parent = parent.children[0]; //  first child
  }
  return depth;
}

and after that also calculate the margin left based on teh depth factor
calculateMarginLeft(depth) {
  const marginLeft = depth * 12 + 'px';
  return marginLeft;
}

I think it should work!

What if a parent has more than one child and for instance the second child has a deeper nesting than the first one?
